# How to get the value of a html select in AngularJS after using a filter in the ng-options expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used a filter in my ng-options expression to convert all the options to uppercase but now when I want to get the value that the user selected I get a undefined

here is my select

```
<select name="selectThings" class="form-control"  
                                    id="selectThings" 
                                    ng-model="selectThings"

                                    ng-options="thing.name as (thing.name | uppercase) for thing in thinglist" 
                                    ng-change="submitSelectedValThing()"
                                    required>
</select>
```

and here is how I'm trying to get the value that the user selected

```
$scope.selectThings.name;
```

but I get an undefined error in that line, the code used to work fine before I added that filter

here is my full controller

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('ThingCtrl', ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {


           $scope.submitSelectedValThing = function () {
            $scope.$watch('thing.Name', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                if (!$scope.thing.Name || newVal === oldVal) return;
                    // now do stuff here with $scope.selectedThing
                    console.log('the value is ' + $scope.selectThings.name);
            });
           console.log($scope.selectThings.name);

           };




         }]);
```

Comment: "the code used to work fine before I added that filter"  Can you post the code the way it looked when it worked?

Answer (score 0):

What you really want here is

```
<select ng-model="selectedThing" ng-options="formattedThingName as (thing.name | uppercase) for thing in thinglist"></select>
```

The selected value is now accessible via $scope.selectedThing

I'm not really sure about the outcome from your code, but my guess is that it was re-assigning the value of the uppercase filter to the thing.name.

Comment: well I want to get the value that user selected, so I can use that value in my controller. I tried putting in my controller this "$scope.selectThings.name;" but I get undefined, is there a way to get the value of a select if you use a filter like uppercase?

Comment: I removed the ng-model for sake of keeping it short, but Ill update to include it. You should get the desired effect.

Comment: I get the same undefined error, I edited my questions I saw the type error in 
"for thingin thinglist"  I fixed it to "for thing in thinglist", but I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can add a watch to the value the drop down is bound to and then compare values in the expression evaluator like so:

```
        //
        // Handle dropdown on select
        $scope.$watch('selectThings.name', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if (!$scope.selectThings.name || newVal === oldVal) return;
                // now do stuff here with $scope.selectThings.name
            );
        });
```

Comment: I updated my code sample but I can't gurantee it will work without seeing how selectThings.name is defined and the rest of your code. Please make a JSFiddle or provide a working code sample.